# How to get tensorflow session from within tf.estimator.Estimator?

Tags: tensorflow

Where is this documented? Are estimators still recommended or are they just added tech debt onto your learning curve?

Want to get a sess inside the functions you pass to estimator. model_fn, input_fn etc.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. Recommended for what? And what exactly do you want do do with session from inside estimator?

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Estimators are being phased-out in TF 2.0. Keras Models are now the recommended high-level API [(youtube source)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5c-vg4rjBw&list=PLQY2H8rRoyvzoUYI26kHmKSJBedn3SQuB&index=4)

I'm not sure what you want to do with the session, but a convenient way to access it is using a [SessionRunHook](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py)

You can define a new hook, and pass it to the estimator with e.g.

```py
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=[my_custom_hook])
```

Comment: Sorry is that "phased-in" or "phased-out in"

Comment: I don't think Keras supports multiple batch-sizes in one graph though so I doubt they can kill estimators.

Comment: it was "phased-out" -- thanks for pointing that out.

most of the keras layers don't accept a batch size in their target_shape arguments.  the batch size usually gets computed based on the first dimension of the input size.  [(example)](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape)

Comment: Whoa are you *sure* it is being phased-out? This will like cause panic.

Comment: Just checked with the dev advocate and they confirmed tf.estimator is still around for tf 2.0.

Comment: It would save me and my coworkers a lot of work if they aren't being phased out.  That's not the impression I got from the dev summit this year.  Watch the youtube link above if you get the chance

Comment: I have a feeling everything in the tf.estimator and keras space is broken. They are probably trying to fix it slowly. I am hitting many, many errors in in the APIs (serialization and tensorboard). I think internally they are using pure tensorflow and not bothering with keras or estimator for anything but vanilla ML problems.

The thing I really, really care about is the logging, serialization and viz stack.  It is very difficult to navigate where that is going.